# Copy only letters from clipboard to textbox

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm struggling with copying only letters from clipboard to textbox. I've tried to filter the clipboard and replacing it with only letters with regex, but I want to clipboard stay untouched.

I've tried:

```
private void Schowek()
    {
        string schoweczek;
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
        {
            schoweczek = Clipboard.GetText();
            var schoweczek2 = Regex.Replace(schoweczek, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
            Clipboard.SetText(schoweczek2);

        }
    }
```

and

```
private void textBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            Schowek();
        }
    }
```

but I think it's not the most efficient way to do that.

UPDATE:
I've come up with sth like this, tho it's not working:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string checkstr=textBox1.Text;
        char[] checkchar = checkstr.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < checkstr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(checkchar[i])){


            }
            else
            {
                checkchar[i] = '\0';

            }

        }

       checkstr=String.Join("", checkchar);
       textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + checkstr;
```

Comment: Do you want to modify the text in a specific Textbox or in general?

Comment: specific textbox. I'm making something like register form and I need some of textboxes filter different chars, like: Name (accept only letters) but adress (accept letters/digits) etc.

Comment: (it's for school project, our teacher demands it ;/)

Comment: On a side note is is very unusual to modify the clipboard data this way unless your app is a clipboard helper tool (I used a tool that removes formatting).

Comment: Question says "*I want to clipboard stay untouched*" but the last non-trivial line of the first code block contains `Clipboard.SetText(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to hack the native paste function into pasting something other than what is in the clipboard, or changing the contents of the clipboard, you can just subscribe to an event of the textbox and "correct" it's value there.

If you are okay with allowing the user to input anything into the textbox and then cleaning the value once they move to the next control, use the validation events which will only fire after you move to the next field.

If you want instant correction, use the text changed event. But be careful about the amount of code you run in this event as it will fire multiple times rapidly when the user is typing in it. If possible, use the event that only fires after the textbox looses focus.

There is no need to touch the Clipboard at any point for what you are trying to do.

[EDIT]
Also, be wary of disallowing characters in people's names. There are lots of people who have numbers and weird characters in their names.
[Falsehoods Programmers Beleive About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Yup, but my teacher allowed only letters in name textbox. I'm trying with if (textbox1.text.contains) but it's not working properly; /

Comment: My answer was referring to where and when you need to correct the value in the textbox, as to HOW to do it, that's already been answered. There are multiple approaches including regex, the allowed charracters array from SchlaWiener's post or Char.IsLetter().

Put two and two together and you've solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

A very common way to achive this for a specific textbox instance is this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   // pseudo-code, fell free to implement it yourself.
   if(!IsAllowed(e.KeyChar))
       e.Handled = true;
}

private readonly char[] allowed = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
private bool IsAllowed(char c)
{
    return allowed.Contains(c);
}
```

**Update**

You could use a MaskedTextBox but I think your teacher will consider this cheating ;)

I could think of:

```
private bool reenter = false;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (reenter || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) return;

    var in = textBox1.Text.ToCharArray(); 
    var out = Filter(input).ToArray();
    var output = new String(out);

    if (!textBox1.Text.Equals(output))
    {
        reenter = true;
        textBox1.Text = output;
        reenter = false;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<char> Filter(IEnumerable<char> input)
{
     foreach(var c in input)
       if (IsAllowed(c))
           yield return c;
}
```

**Update 2**

I just modified your own solution a bit.

First you have to prevent the TextChanged event from fireing multiple times (it fires also if you set the Text from code). You can either set a boolean variable like I did with `reenter` in my previous example or compare text and new text and only set it's value if different.

Setting a value inside the array to `'\0'` is wrong because `\0` is the string terminator and every char after that is ignored. So if you paste `a1b` from the clipboard you get a char array { 'a', '\0', 'b' }. NET does not need a string terminator so you would see the result as "a\0b" but if you set the textbox value it will be only `a` not `ab`

Anyway, this is my solution. It uses another array and I also memorize `SelectionStart` to prevent the cursor from jumping to the first position after the text changes.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string checkstr = textBox1.Text;
        char[] checkchar = checkstr.ToCharArray();
        char[] newchar = new char[checkstr.Length];

        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < checkstr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(checkchar[i]))
            {
                newchar[pos] = checkchar[i];
                pos++;
            }
        }

        checkstr = String.Join("", newchar);
        if (textBox1.Text != checkstr)
        {
            var start = textBox1.SelectionStart;
            textBox1.Text = checkstr;
            textBox1.SelectionStart = start;
        }

}
```

Comment: I have to allow user to copy text from clipboard (mouse rightclick and paste)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
string strClip = Clipboard.GetText();
string textvalue  = Regex.Replace(strClip, @"\d", "");
```

first you copy the text from the Clipboard the you replace the digits with "".It work fine i test it.

Answer (score 0):

Take another point of view:
Consider "being" the textbox and watching what is entered or pasted. Then drop anything that is not allowed or (better user experience): allow any input, but deny "OK" and show an error until only valid input is present.